# Query Session no longer respond

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute the following T-SQL Statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @nRows INT = 1
DECLARE @DataCancellazione DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
CREATE TABLE #IDToDel (ID BIGINT)

WHILE @nRows > 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #IDToDel
  SELECT TOP 5000 LogID
  FROM MioDB.Test
  WHERE CAST(ReceivedDate AS date) < @DataCancellazione

  SELECT @nRows = @@ROWCOUNT

  DELETE RM WITH (PAGLOCK)
  FROM MioDB.Test  RM WITH (PAGLOCK)
  INNER JOIN #IDToDel TBD ON RM.LogID  = TBD.ID

  TRUNCATE TABLE #IDToDel
END
ROLLBACK
```

When I launch the execution the query window seems to no longer respond and without having particular increase of CPUTime and DiskIO on the process. Can anyone help me thanks.

Comment: Because you're using a Loop, which perform *awfully* in T-SQL. It looks like you want to batch, but there's likely no need to for temporary table to achieve that, and SQL Server can handle significantly more than 5000 rows in a single `DELETE`. How many rows are you actually expecting to delete in total here?

Comment: Side note, there is no such thing as SSMS 2019; the latest version of SSMS is SSMS 18 which was coincidentally released in 2018 (but it is *not* called SSMS 2018).

Comment: @Larnu at least 4.000.000 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I think you're overly complicating the problem. SQL Server can *easily* handle processing millions of rows in one go, and I suspect that you could likely do this in a few 1M row batches. If you have at least 4,000,000 rows you want to delete, then at 5,000 a batch that will take **800** iterations.

There is also no need for the temporary table, a `DELETE` can make use of a `TOP`, so you can just delete that many rows each cycle. I define this with a variable, and then pass that (1,000,000 rows). This would mean everything is deleted in 4 iterations, not 800. You may want to reduce the size a little, but I would suggest that 500,000 is easy pickings for instance.

This gives you the following more succinct batch:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--The following transaction level seems like a terrible idea when you're performing DDL statements. Don't, just don't.
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 

DECLARE @BatchSize int = 1000000,
        @DataCancellazione date = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE());
SELECT 1; --Dataset with 1 row

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
    FROM MioDB.Test --A Schema called "MioDB" is a little confusing
    WHERE ReceivedDate < @DataCancellazione; --Casting ReceivedDate would have had no change to the query
                                             --And could well have slowed it down.
```